# angular search specific columns by filter

Tags: angular, search, filter, pipe, ngfor

I created table with *ngfor in angular. and put a search filter in this table. Code is below.

```
<tr *ngFor="let new of variables | orderBy: key: reverse | filter:term" style="width: 100%;">
  <td *ngFor="let col of index" id="tablo_data">
    {{new[col]}}
  </td>
</tr>
```

this code does the search over the entire table. but I want to search in selected columns. Input type code below:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search Here" [(ngModel)]="term">
</div>
```

and term define:

```
  term: string;
```

all json data define is

```
  variables: Variables[] = [];
```

Comment: Do you mean angularJS?

Comment: no, angular8-9-10

Answer (score 1):

The filter would be a custom pipe in your case, and you have full control over it. Try:

```
@Pipe({
    name: 'filter'
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(data: Array<Array<any>>, term: string, colNum: string): any {
        if (term && Array.isArray(data) && colNum) {
            return data.filter((row: Array<any>) => (row[colNum] as string).toUpperCase() === term.toUpperCase());
        } else {
            return data;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

For your search `input`, when you bind the model with `term`, include an array of the headers for whatever columns you want to be included in the search.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search Here" [(ngModel)]="term['id','Name']">
</div>
```